# How does Extra Attack and Two-Weapon-Fighting work for a fighter?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, two-weapon-fighting

Since all PC's are capable of two weapon fighting, is the phrase *"you can use two weapon fighting..."* just redundant or is it giving you the two-weapon-fighting fighting-style of a fighter, so I can take great-weapon-fighting, dueling, or archery instead?

Secondly would a fifth level Eldritch knight with the Dual Wielder feat and Two-Weapon-Fighting fighting-style be able to:

1. Shoot hand crossbow
2. Throw hand-axe
3. Summon his battle axe and war hammer with his bonus action
4. Action surge to attack with summoned weapons one of which will have booming blade on it, and will that attack generate any additional actions?

Does his 5th level extra attack come into play during first attack, or at any other time?

Comment: Hi Francisco, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the site. Please be aware we have a 1 question per post policy and you seem to be asking multiple related question. Please [edit] your post to focus on a single problem you are having, then we can help refine it. Until then this post may be closed.

Comment: Related questions: "[Confused about fighter's Two Weapon Fighting Style](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49797)" and "[How many attacks can a fighter with two-weapon fighting make at 5th level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55587)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many attacks can a fighter with two-weapon fighting make at 5th level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55587/how-many-attacks-can-a-fighter-with-two-weapon-fighting-make-at-5th-level)

Comment: Thank you helping re-format my question linksassin

Comment: Just to clarify; [there is a difference between "Two Weapon Fighting" and "two weapon fighting"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69525/12193). The first has is specific to the fighting style, the second is for anyone that has two weapons to attack with.

Comment: @Ben I would say the correct terms are "Two-Weapon Fighting" and (the) "Two-Weapon Fighting Style". I believe both are capitalized as used [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49797)

Comment: that is what i am asking does dual wielder apply to both or just one, if so the taking TWS is only necessary it i want the extra bonus to second attack right? otherwise i can just use tws with dual weilding, with the ability to +2 Archery or Dueling. Additionally the Hand Crossbow has the property of Light, which says makes it ideal for two weapon fighting, so does the melee requirement take precedence over the light property description saying it is ideal?

Comment: Neither the Dual Wielder feat nor the Two-Weapon Fighting Style are required to use Two-Weapon Fighting. And neither is required to use the other. This is somewhat explained in "[Does Dual-Wielder require to have Two-Weapon Fighting as a prerequisite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108284)" and above. In terms of your question regarding Hand Crossbow there exists the following: "[What function does the "light" weapon property serve on the hand crossbow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44773)" stating that the Light property does (effectively) nothing on the Hand Crossbow.

Comment: You say that one of your weapons will have *booming blade* on it, are you aware that casting a spell requires its own action, Cast A Spell, which is separate from the Attack action? See these questions: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96206, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114006, and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55587/how-many-attacks-can-a-fighter-with-two-weapon-fighting-make-at-5th-level), the *maximum* amount of attacks you can make as a level 5 Fighter is 5 attacks. However, this is only if you have your bonus action free to make the final attack. By summoning the extra weapon(s), you forfeit 1 attack there.

- Main Action to attack (shoot crossbow)

  - Extra Attack triggers, after taking the attack action (throw handaxe)
- Bonus Action to Summon extra weapon(s)
- Action Surge to attack (hammer)

  - Extra attack triggers.

However, if we want to get technical, two-weapon fighting states that you use your Bonus Action to make a second attack with your other hand (PHB p. 195 emphasis mine):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, **you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.** You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative. If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it.

So this means, that in your specific example, you already give up your bonus action by attacking with your off-hand (axe or crossbow), therefore making you unable to summon the extra weapons.

And finally, just a last clarification (thanks to [Medix2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/36521/medix2) for pointing it out); the Weapon bond feature does allow for you to bond with up to two weapons, but only *one* weapon can be summoned at a time (PHB p. 75, emphasis mine):

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself, you can't be disarmed of that weapon unless you are incapacitated. If it is on the same plane of existence,
>   you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand. **You can have up to two bonded weapons, but can summon only one at a time with your bonus action.**

So, instead, you could use your bonus action to summon one weapon, then attack up to 4 times with it.

- Bonus Action (summon bonded weapon)
- Main Action (to attack with bonded weapon)

  - Extra attack (with same weapon)
- Action Surge (to attack again with same weapon)

  - Extra attack (with same weapon)

Ultimately it's less cinematic, unfortunately (shooting and throwing weapons, and then summoning your hammer and axe to charge in swinging), but this way you can still gain the most attacks.

Comment: Using the word "summon" instead of "draw" seems odd. Also Extra Attack does not occur *after* the Attack action it is *part of it*. Also I'm not sure where Two-Weapon Fighting really exists in the original questions, it seems unclear

Comment: @Medix2 it's a feature of the Eldritch Knight archetype: *"If [the weapon] is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand."* (PHB p. 75)

Comment: Oh! Then you may want to mention that they could not summon two weapons. Or that Dual Wielder would not allow them to do so.

Comment: That is true. However, going from this specific example, they wouldn't be able to summon any. But I will make that point regardless. Nice catch!